# Clickonce: setup.exe opens .application file in browser. Normal?

Tags: .net, firefox, .net-2.0, installation, clickonce

I've just deployed our first ClickOnce application. Unfortunately it requires far more than one click to install our application.

- The user downloads the setup.exe and executs it
- The default browser pops up (e.g. Firefox) and the user has to download an ourapp.application file
- Afterwards he can start this file and after some security warnings the regular setup starts

This seems way to much for me and I guess that most of our customers will be really confused by this rather unusual method.

I've seen at Seesmic (the Seesmic Desktop app) that it is indeed possible to let the setup.exe directly start the ClickOnce procedure. Is the same possible with .NET 2.0? Or are there workarounds?

Best regards,

inTrance

Answer (score 3):

This usually means that you have not defined the MIME types on the server. These are the MIME types you need in order to host a ClickOnce application:

.application  --> application/x-ms-application

.manifest  --> application/x-ms-application

.deploy   --> application/octet stream

If you are deploying .Net 3.5 as a prerequisite, you need these as well:

.msp --> application/microsoftpatch

.msu --> application/microsoftupdate

If you have vsto apps, you need this one:

.vsto --> application/x-ms-vsto

RobinDotNet

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/da/firefox/addon/1608) to make running ClickOnce applications easier.

Comment: Hm.... So there is no way to create a ClickOnce application like http://seesmic.com/seesmic_desktop/windows/ which directly starts the setup from the setup.exe?

Comment: The manifest of ClickOnce has a MIME type, and there must be "something" that knows how to handle it (like a Web browser knows by default how to handle text/html). IE knows these manifests by itself. Firefox needs the extension.

Comment: The situation improves a little bit with this configuration:

AddType application/x-ms-application application
AddType application/x-ms-manifest manifest
AddType application/octet-stream deploy

But still - You have to download the application file. 

There has to be some way to achieve the same as Seesmic with their Dektop App!

Comment: I was able to resolve the error of downloading the file by adding the MSVS Tools for Office to the deploy/publish component dependencies